# Getting a string from a scanner when a number is entered

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that ask a user for 2 numbers and then ask the user to pick a command from a menu by entering the correspond number to the command. 
I can write the program if i take the input as an Int but cannot figure it out for a string, also it has to be a string.
I am having problems when it enters the while loop to validate the user input it does not stop when the statement is false it will stay in the loop I can not figure out what i am doing wrong.
Here is the code i have.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ab {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    double L;
    System.out.print("Enter the left operand: ");
    L = stdIn.nextDouble();
    double R;
    System.out.print("Enter the right operand: ");
    R = stdIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1 -> Multiplication");
    System.out.println("2 -> Division");
    System.out.println("3 -> Addition");
    System.out.println("4 -> Subraction");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    String input;
    System.out.print("Choose one of the following commands by enterning the corresponding number: ");
    input = stdIn.next();
    System.out.println();
    while (!input.equals(1) && !input.equals(2) && !input.equals(3) && !input.equals(4)) {
      System.out.print("Invalid entry, please type a valid number (1, 2, 3 or 4): ");
      input = stdIn.next();
      System.out.println();
      if (input.equals(1)) {
        System.out.print(L + " * " + R + " = " + (L * R));
      } else if (input.equals(2)) {
        System.out.print(L + " / " + R + " = " + (L / R));
      } else if (input.equals(3)) {
        System.out.print(L + " + " + R + " = " + (L + R));
      } else {
        System.out.print(L + " - " + R + " = " + (L - R));
      }
    }
    stdIn.close();
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `input = stdIn.next();` is taking input as `String`
while your comparison is against integer. So a `String` never equals `Int`

You may try changing your while loop condition to:

```
while (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2") && !input.equals("3") && !input.equals("4"))
```

note the double quote around the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Is answered, but check this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ab {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    double L;
    System.out.print("Enter the left operand: ");
    L = stdIn.nextDouble();
    double R;
    System.out.print("Enter the right operand: ");
    R = stdIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1 -> Multiplication");
    System.out.println("2 -> Division");
    System.out.println("3 -> Addition");
    System.out.println("4 -> Subraction");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    String input;
    System.out.print("Choose one of the following commands by enterning the corresponding number: ");

    input = stdIn.next();

    while (true) {

        if (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2") && !input.equals("3") && !input.equals("4")) {
            System.out.print("Invalid entry, please type a valid number (1, 2, 3 or 4): ");
            input = stdIn.next();
        } else {
            if (input.equals("1")) {
                System.out.print(L + " * " + R + " = " + (L * R));
                break;
            } else if (input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.print(L + " / " + R + " = " + (L / R));
                break;
            } else if (input.equals("3")) {
                System.out.print(L + " + " + R + " = " + (L + R));
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print(L + " - " + R + " = " + (L - R));
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    stdIn.close();
}
```

}